# How can I extract all text between single full stops (i.e. ignore `...`) with a re2 regex?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, re2

How can I extract all text between single full stops (i.e. ignore `...`) with a re2 regex?

I am using the `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` function in BigQuery which uses https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax.

From the following example:

`This is... a.. sentence. It is just an example.`

I would like the query to extract

`This is... a.. sentence.` and  `It is just an example.`

I am specifically interested in whether this is possible using SQL functions in BigQuery rather than introducing another tool

Comment: Splitting text into sentences is a complex NLP task, you can't rely on a single regex unless you are dealing with very specific structured data (that are probably machine-generated). However, you seem to have arbitrary sentences, you should think of using some more sophisticated tool/feature here.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew. It doesn't need to be exact for this use-case. It feels like this should be possible with a regex, but I'm not sure whether re2 is powerful enough

Comment: You are right, RE2 does not support lookarounds, and these constructs are usually used in similar regexps. Certainly, you may write some good enough pattern using negated character classes with alternations, but it just won't be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below workaround

```
select text, regexp_replace(sentence, r'(#)(\.+)(#)', r'\2') sentence
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(split(trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(text, r'(\.+)', r'#\1#'), r'(\#\.\#)', r'####'), '####'), '####')) sentence
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]